# Reverse "heat" in one column of a heatmap()

Tags: r

I'm using `heatmap` to plot the leader for each of the respective pitching performance categories for some baseball data.  My problem is that I need to reverse the "heat" of just one of the columns, because the best ERA is the lowest, not the highest.  Here's the code. `mlb2010` is data that was imported from a `SQL` database via `RSQLite`.

```
mlb10 <- sapply(2:length(mlb2010), function(i) {
    mlb2010[, i] <- as.numeric(mlb2010[, i]) 
    })

rc <- rainbow(nrow(mlb10), start = 0, end = .3)
cc <- rainbow(ncol(mlb10), start = 0, end = .3)

heatmap(mlb10, col = rev(heat.colors(256)), scale = "column", 
        Rowv = NULL, Colv = NA, RowSideColors = rc, ColSideColors = cc, 
        margins = c(5,10), labRow = c(mlb2010$team), labCol = names(al2010)[-1],
        xlab = "Performance factors", ylab =  "Team",
        main = c("Relating Performance to Payroll", "2010 MLB Season"))
```

I have tried the `revC` argument in `heatmap` with no success.  Is that what I should be using?  Or does that reorder all of the columns, and not what is inside the column?  I've also tried an `sapply` over the colors to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As a simple workaround, plot `-ERA` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per request from OP, posting the basics of the solution.

Just do `ml10$ERA <- -ml10$ERA`  to reverse the order, then plot as in the post.